# Datatables con Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, jquery, css, datatables

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que muestra un catalogo de celdas de producciónm debido a que son demasiados datos los que me arroja al hacer el Query, quise intentar utilizar el Plugind de Jquery, Datatables, intente primero hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Zona</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#grid').DataTable();
        });
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <table id="grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Numero Zona</th>
                    <th>Nombre Zona</th>
                    <th>Perimetro</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Zona 1</td>
                    <td>Perimetro 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Zona 2</td>
                    <td>Perimetro 2</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

De una forma estatica, logro el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera si puedo obtener los valores de mi tabla en el datatable, pero cuando quiero llenar el datatable de modo dinamico, es decir, directamente desde mi base de datos, no me muestra mi tabla en Datatables solo en una tabla sin más, anexo el código de como lo quiero mostrar dinamicamente:

```
<div class="tabla">
<table id="grid" class="table table-hover dt-responsive nowrap ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Hostname</th>
            <th>Bay</th>
            <th>Rack</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        {% for row in result %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{row ['HOSTNAME']}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{row ['BAY']}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{row ['RACK']}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{row ['DESCRIPTION']}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="boton btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalLong">Edit </button> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        </tr>
        {% endfor%}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Cabe destacar que estoy utilizando Python flask, por eso las etiquetas entre llaves del html.

Comment: Estás usando ajax para cargar los datos dinámicos?

Comment: No, lo hago mediante Python y Flask

Comment: Debes ejecutar $('#grid').DataTable(); justo después de que la tabla tenga todos los datos que vas a mostrar, también revisa si te saca algún error en consola

Comment: @CamiloVasquez, eso exactamente hago, cheque los errores de consola y me muestra lo siguiente :

Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
    at bootstrap.min.js:6

segun yo, es problema de colocar el JS de Jquery antes que el de Bootstrap, ya lo realize, pero de igual manera me muestra lo mismo.

Comment: Claro, primero debes llamar jquery, luego datatables y por último bootstrap, es extraño que te siga sacando ese error si ya lo tienes en el orden que debe ser

Comment: @CamiloVasquez .... he resuelto todos los errores de consola, colocando bien los scripts y links, y una ves que se ejecuta Jquery para el Datatables, no me sigue generando la tabla como tal, si no simplemente como una tabla normal y cheque la consola y me arrojo el siguiente error:



 $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (power:9164)
    at i (jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.12.0.min.js:2)



¿sabes por qué?. Gracias

Comment: $(...).DataTable is not a function, estás seguro que estas importando de manera correcta el script datatables.min.js? ese error significa que falta ese archivo

Comment: Tenes 4 th y 5 td, no va a cargar nunca el plugin. Tenes que agregar un th sin contenido para el td que tiene el button.

Comment: Puedes cargar los datos usando un objeto(array,lista generica) mira el siguiente link
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Answer (score 2):

Para cargar datos de forma dinámica debe de hacerse desde una llamada ajax, y ejecutarla al construir la tabla, no puedes crear los registros de la tabla sin el constructor del plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/server_processing.php"
    } );
} );
```

Documentación: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Comment: Muchas gracias, eso resuelve completamente mi duda del porque no puedo hacerlo. Ahora, sé más o menos como funciona ajax, pero todos los ejemplos que encuentro es con php, no sé como implementarlo de una manera correcta para python flask ¿podrias ayudarme?.

Comment: @Roger sinceramente no conozco Python Flask. Pero no tiene nada de complejidad el suministrale datos al plugin. Lo que recibe es un **objeto JSON**, por lo que debes de ver como transformar tu data en un objeto JSON, imprimirla y en el apartado de `ajax` darle la **ruta** de donde lo haz suministrado. Espero y me explique.